# Do I have to use clamps or does the sealant do the same thing...I need help

Tags: maintenance, exhaust, muffler

I have to put my muffler pipe in but I'm kinda confused...can I put the pipe on and use the sealant would that be alright to do or do you have to use clamps ?

Comment: do you have pictures?

Comment: Which make and model?

Answer (score 2):

To fix two parts of an exhaust together you use sealant or paste to help seal the gaps which are present on almost all joints. Then you fit a clamp to compress the joint and lock it together. Paste alone will not hold an exhaust together.